# can I uninstall UBUNTU from within Windows?

Tags: system-installation

I was successfully using UBUNTU for a while until after a silly mistake I deleted some files. I had the system running together with my Windows but now I cannot reboot in Ubuntu, it gives me an error message and says that some files are missing :(

Is there a way I can uninstall Ubuntu from within Windows?

Or can I just install the same version of UBUNTU? would the two systems not collide?

Comment: if you can mention the error , someone can definitely solve it , you dont need re-installing or un installing at this moment .

Answer (score 1):

No you can't (but actually you can), supposing you have done a conventional job of reformatting a partition on your HDD as `ext4` and installing Ubuntu on that. Windows will not recognize that format (unless you have some third-party software installed, like [these](http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/) or [these](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-read-ext3ext4-linux-partition-from-windows-7.html) ones) and therefore you won't see it anywhere in Windows to be able to delete it or anything.

As for reinstalling, I think you would only have the option to remove previous version installed before being able to install again on the same partition, leaving no chance of *collision* by definition.

PS: to give so probably more sensible links, taken from the already given one, (some of) the third-party softwares are [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/), [Linux Reader](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/) and [Ext2Read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/).

Answer (score 1):

Hello Masha and welcome to Ubuntu!

You can, in fact, install Ubuntu again and replace the broken version on your computer. If you wish to do so, then proceed to install Ubuntu again, *but* when you are asked to choose where to install Ubuntu, select *Something Else*. The next screen may look rather intimidating, but don't worry, I am here to help. At this screen, select the row that lists *ext4* under the Type column in the chart, and then click the minus sign near the bottom of the window. After, you will note the words "free space" being in place of ext4. Click this row again and then the plus sign near the bottom of the page. A window will appear and in it you must choose "/" as the "mount point" using the selection box in the window, and ensure that "Beginning of this space" and "Logical" are selected, too, as well as "Ext4 Journaling File System" for the "Use as" box. Click OK and then "Install Now" at the bottom of the previous window.

Now, the installation will proceed as it did when you first installed Ubuntu. Let me know if you require assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you do what Sushantp606 said, just tell people what your mistake was and see if it can be undone.

If you really want to uninstall ubuntu though, the LiveCD could be used to uninstall it as well. On the disk partitioning window you could format the disk partition where ubuntu is installed, as if you are formatting your hard drive for a fresh installation. Be careful though, you don't want to destroy anything important(like your Windows installation). And avoid this method for as long as you can.